# Can't get form data to be submitted to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to send form data to a database, seems to be doing it but then I check the database and nothing appears. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I followed a Youtube tutorial almost to the letter other than adding my own variables so not too sure where I've gone wrong.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/loginreg/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="formDiv">
    <form method="POST" action="registration/connect.php">
    <label>First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/><br/>
    <label>Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/><br/>
    <label>Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/><br/>
    <label>Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/><br/>
    <label>Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" /> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php  

    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not conneced to server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'registration'))
    {
        echo 'Database not selected';
    }

        $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];




    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$email','$password')";



    header("refresh:2; url=http://localhost/loginreg/index.html");
?>
```

Comment: `$sql` is just a variable. You need to use `mysqli` functions to send that. That also will open you to SQL injections. You should parameterize it. Also pleassse don't store plain text passwords. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php I would also recommend not using youtube tutorials (if this is what it gave you it than it  lacks many best practices)

Comment: Just like your last attempt at this question there is no code that actually inserts the values into the database.  You at least have an SQL statement this time, but there still is no code that actually executes that statement to insert the values to the database.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for your help here, as I'm sure you can tell I'm new to this. This isn't for anything major so I'm not too concerned about security issues just yet my aim is to just get it working first of all, could you perhaps edit my code so I can see where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After your `$sql` variabl, add something like this:

`if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo 'success';
}`

Like Chris85 says, this is not completely secure and will open you up to SQL injections.

Comment: While on the right track, this has the unfortunate downside of weaponizing the query. It's really a bandage on code that's fundamentally busted.

Comment: OP uses procedural, this is for oop

Comment: @nogad Both can work together. It's not recommended but it does work.